# Are bobble heads single use in Fallout 76?

Tags: fallout-76

I have a bobble head which will increase my agility for 1 hour. However, I haven’t used it yet because I don’t want it consumed and gone forever.

So, if I use it, will I be able to use it again, and again? Or, should I save it for that s.p.e.c.i.a.l. moment when I really need agility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are single use only.  Once used, they are removed from your inventory.  I have found multiples of the same bobblehead though, so it is possible to get them again.  Also, due to the nature of loot in this game, I believe they do respawn over time.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for the information. Good to know they will at least respawn eventually. Thank you

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker I don't think they spawn in the same exact locations time and time again - they are somewhat harder to find than normal loot, so their spawns are often in obscure places.  I remember I found one once behind a picture frame in a display case of the White Springs Golf Club.  Also note, that if playing with others, a bobblehead that you found may not be there for your teammate.  They appear to be uniquely spawned for each player.  I've experienced that when playing with a friend.

Comment: That's good info to know. Greatly appreciate it. I've found a few, just been reluctant to use them due to the rarity and potential single use. Thanks again

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Sadly, I pretty much consume them upon finding them because they weigh 1 each, and the space limitations in the game so far make it hard to store them, especially since they are only temporary.

Comment: That's also a good point. I found inventory management has been quite a pain. Constantly trying to find a bench to scrap my items and then heading to a station or my camp to unload due to weight limitations

Comment: Spawn locations are the same, they just don't always respawn and the type of bobblehead is random. For example, I've found them at a military camp many times in the same exact spot. Always a different bobblehead and it's not always there (either because of not spawning or because someone else took it; not sure).

Comment: I can confirm @Shelby115's statement. I have found bobbleheads more than once in the same spot (different bobblheads each time), and I've found the same bobblehead in more than one place.